# Fiji get a 16bit tiff stack with unknown tags after importing sequences

Tags: matlab

In Fiji, I import sequences to get a tiff stack image over 5GB. I cannot see the detailed information in the property, such as Width, Height, Bit depth. The original depth is 16bit. When I use "imfinfo" in Matlab, it always shows 1 but not the length of the stack. Can anyone help me solve this problem? I would like to appreciate your kindness.

Below is the feedback from Matlab when I use imfinfo.

```
info_red=imfinfo('C:\Users\MyDoc\Desktop\Background Subtraction\FluoRed.tif')

info_red= 

                 Filename: 'C:\Users\MyDoc\Desktop\Background   Subtraction\FluoRed.tif'
              FileModDate: '02-Sep-2014 07:09:51'
                 FileSize: 5.3701e+09
                   Format: 'tif'
            FormatVersion: []
                    Width: 1388
                   Height: 1040
                 BitDepth: 16
                ColorType: 'grayscale'
          FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]
                ByteOrder: 'little-endian'
           NewSubFileType: 0
            BitsPerSample: 16
              Compression: 'Uncompressed'
PhotometricInterpretation: 'BlackIsZero'
             StripOffsets: 230904
          SamplesPerPixel: 1
             RowsPerStrip: 1040
          StripByteCounts: 2887040
              XResolution: []
              YResolution: []
           ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
                 Colormap: []
      PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                TileWidth: []
               TileLength: []
              TileOffsets: []
           TileByteCounts: []
              Orientation: 1
                FillOrder: 1
         GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
           MaxSampleValue: 65535
           MinSampleValue: 0
             Thresholding: 1
                   Offset: 8
         ImageDescription: 'ImageJ=1.49b
images=1860
frames=1860
finterval=3
tunit=min
loop=false
min=30...'
              UnknownTags: [2x1 struct]
```

Comment: Maybe try `jhead` program to get info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when importing tiff stacks with Matlab, you can use the [tiff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff-class.html) class to get information about your stack, as well as actually opening them.

For example, if you use this:

```
t = Tiff('FluoRed.tif','r')
```

you will get a description of your stack which looks somewhat similar to what you get with imfinfo, that is you get a structure in which you can access its fields using standard dot notation. Here is an example with a stack named 'OriginalStack.tif' on my computer:

```
t = 

                  TIFF File: '/Documents/MATLAB/OriginalStack.tif'
                       Mode: 'r'
    Current Image Directory: 1
           Number Of Strips: 1
                SubFileType: Tiff.SubFileType.Default
                Photometric: Tiff.Photometric.RGB
                ImageLength: 364
                 ImageWidth: 460
               RowsPerStrip: 364
              BitsPerSample: 8
                Compression: Tiff.Compression.None
               SampleFormat: Tiff.SampleFormat.UInt
            SamplesPerPixel: 3
        PlanarConfiguration: Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky
           ImageDescription: ImageJ=1.48v
images=20
slices=20
loop=false

                Orientation: Tiff.Orientation.TopLeft
```

For instance, you can get the image width like so:

```
Width = t.getTag('ImageWidth')
```

As you can see, there is a field in the structure called 'ImageDescription', which tells you that there are 20 images in your stack (well my stack actually :). You could manage to get this information with structure indexing, but it's cumbersome since using

```
t.getTag('ImageDescription')
```

returns a character array and you would need to play around with regular expressions, for instance, to get the actual number of images.

**EDIT:** here is how you could do to retrieve the number of slices in your stack:

1) Assign a variable name to the 'ImageDescription' tag from the tiff class object:

```
ImageDes = t.getTag('ImageDecription');
```

2) Then use regular expressions to look for numbers present in the character array:

```
NumberSlices = regexp(ImageDes,'\d*','match')
```

In my case (20 slices), I get the following:

```
NumberSlices = 

    '1'    '48'    '20'    '20'
```

The first 2 numbers are in ImageJ 1.48 so we don't want them, however you can fetch any of the last two numbers and you're good to go:

```
NumberSlices = str2double(NumberSlices{3})
```

If not, the simplest solution in my opinion is to use the output from imfinfo like so:

```
NumberImages = length(info_red);
```

which in your case should give 1860.
Sorry if it was very long as an answer; anyhow I think you will find useful the information about the Tiff class if you are to work with stacks in Matlab :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. When I use 'imfinfo',length(info_red)=1. When I use tiff, the result is like this:                         
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown field with tag 50838 (0xc696) encountered.' 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown field with tag 50839 (0xc697) encountered.
In both cases, I cannot get the actual length of the stack (1860). So I cannot do further analysis of these images.

Comment: Hey Lily. I added an alternative solution using regular expressions. However it's weird that using length(info_red) gives 1. I'll wait for your feedback :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can get the length of the stack using your code. But I aim to import some subimages from the stack. However, I cannot use the following code to get the specified image because length(imfinfo) is always 1. When I change the 16bit images into 8bit, it can read the length accurately. 
filename_red='C:\Users\MyDoc\Desktop\Background Subtraction\FluoRed.tif';
imfo_red=imfinfo(filename_red);
Sample=imread(filename_red,900,'Info',imfo_red);
Error using readtif (line 42)
Image index greater than the number of elements in the info struct.

Comment: Mhh that's weird. I'll do some checking and will get back to you.